# With two raspberry pis on the same network, how can I execute a terminal command on one from the other?

Tags: php, raspberry-pi, apache2, raspbian

I have set up two raspberry pis on my network. The first pi [P1] is hosting an apache2 server, and I have a basic index.php webpage running on it. The second pi [P2] is running a mjpg-streamer service. I am able to view the stream on the P1 webpage. What I would like to do is have a button on the P1 webpage that executes a series of terminal commands on P2. The intent is having a way to stop and start the streaming service on P2, from P1.

I have found that using php I can run a command using:

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('ls -lart');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

but this runs a command on P1, how can I run a command on P2?

I got the above examples from: http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

Answer (score 0):

As the PHP is server-side, it can only execute on the server (in this case, P1). If you would like to execute commands on P2 from a web page hosted on P1, you would have to use something client-side such as a Java applet.

Another option would be creating an API, so that clicking the button makes an API call to P2 which calls some function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ssh and a shared key's to execute remote commands on servers.  It's not really a PHP answer, but it's an answer nevertheless.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssh-key-based-authentication-on-a-linux-server

https://www.garron.me/en/go2linux/ssh-sudo-run-commands-remote-server.html